# Cleaning up a scraped HTML List

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract names from a wiki page. Using BeautifulSoup I am able to get a very dirty list (including lots of extraneous items) that I want to clean up, however my attempt to 'sanitise' the list leaves it unchanged.

```
#1).
#Retreive the page
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
weapons_url = 'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/Weapons'
weapons_page = requests.get(weapons_url)
weapons_soup = BeautifulSoup(weapons_page.content, 'html.parser')

#2).    
#Attain the data I need, plus lot of unhelpful data   
flithy_scraped_weapon_names = weapons_soup.find_all('td', href="", title="")

#3a).
#Identify keywords that reoccur in unhelpful:extraneous list items
dirt = ["mm", "predecessor", "File", "image"]
#3b). - Fails
#Remove extraneous data containing above-defined keywords
weapon_names_sanitised = [s for s in flithy_scraped_weapon_names\
    if not any(xs in s for xs in dirt)]

#4).
#Check data
print(weapon_names_sanitised)
#Returns  a list identical to flithy_scraped_weapon_names
```

Comment: Although I doubt this is the end result you're after, your current problem is with `if not any(xs in s for xs in dirt)]` - it should be `if not any(xs in str(s) for xs in dirt)]`, since `s` is not a string in that expression, but the `Tag` does cast to a string successfully.

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty massive step forward for me, so thank you.

Comment: @Grismar by extending my `dirty` list I have bascially solved this issue, so if you post this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this section:

```
weapon_names_sanitised = [s for s in flithy_scraped_weapon_names\
    if not any(xs in s for xs in dirt)]
```

It should instead be:

```
weapon_names_sanitised = [s for s in flithy_scraped_weapon_names\
    if not any(xs in str(s) for xs in dirt)]
```

The reason is that `flithy_scraped_weapon_names` contains `Tag` objects, which will be cast to a string when printed, but need to be explicitly cast to a string for `xs in str(s)` to work as expected.